# MySQL Legacy Code using CURRENT_DATE with inaccuracies

Tags: php, mysql

Just inherited a bug-filled site with some issues with dates and when things appear/disappear.

There is a lot of SQL statements using `CURRENT_DATE` and I believe this could be a possible issue.

Is anyone else aware of any inaccuracies in performance using `CURRENT_DATE` over, say a PHP-derived date string eg `date('Y-m-d H:j',time())`

Comment: CURRENT_DATE returns a date; your PHP expression is in the form of a timestamp. If you use either one when you *should* be using the other, you'll have trouble.

Comment: The PHP expression turns a timestamp into a date as defined by the first parameter.

Comment: No it doesn't. The PHP expression `echo date('Y-m-d H:j', time())` just returned `2013-08-22 07:22` here. In database terminology, that's a timestamp, not a date. `CURRENT_DATE` evaluates to `2013-08-22`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways date comparisons can go wrong. None of them have anything to do with CURRENT_DATE, which has standard, well-defined, consistent behavior.

First, php usually executes on the web server; CURRENT_DATE executes on the database server. Sometimes the web server and the database server are the same machine, but sometimes they're not. Two different servers might be operating with mismatched clocks. And it's at least theoretically possible for the web server and the database server to be in (or to be set to) two different time zones. I've never seen servers set up that way myself, but it's possible.

Second, [your PHP expression returns a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (not a date) in the form of a timestamp (not in the form of a date). CURRENT_DATE returns a date. They're not the same data type. Compare their values carefully. Most developers initially expect an expression like `CURRENT_DATE between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and (CURRENT_DATE + 1)` to be true, but it's not. CURRENT_DATE will be cast to type timestamp (DateTime in MySQL), then compared to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. When it's cast to type timestamp, it will be '2013-08-22 00:00:00'.

Third, it's probably possible to have a format string in PHP that gives you sensibly sorted values in one locale, and differently sorted values in another. PHP docs caution against using date() in "non-English" locales. (Same link.)

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale()
>   and strftime() functions instead of date().